# Window location with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I want to redirect my page to an anchor of itself when an element with a certain class is clicked. This is what I thought would work:

```
$(function()
{
  $('.paginacion').click(function()
  {
    var $this = $(location).attr('href');
    $this += '#nav';
    $(location).attr('href', $this);
  });
});
```

However, I can see how the wanted location is produced in the URL, but a snap later it's gone and it doesn't go to the anchor. What's wrong? Note that I'm pretty dumb with javascrip and jQuery.

Comment: Why not just use `location.href = $this`? (I would also suggest  $url is a better variable name, so as not to get confused with `this`)

Comment: No. Location is not an element. `attr` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the equivalent of assigning to `window.location.href`, you need to use `prop`, not `attr`:

```
$(location).prop('href', $this);
```

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: The issue I explained keeps happening with with `prop` too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not write:

```
$(function () {
  $('.paginacion').click(function()
  {
    var $this = window.location.href;
    $this += '#nav';
    window.location.href = $this;
  });
});
```

Comment: @stuartd That would make sense, then.

Comment: The issue I explained keeps happening with with version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how jQuery works. `.prop` and `.attr` are for DOM elements, not objects like `location`. I don't really understand the point of your code to be completely honest with you, as when `.pagination` is clicked it will just add `#nav` to the location. I'm assuming you want to get the attribute of the clicked element and go to that instead of just adding `#nav`, as that would be pointless.

```js
$(function() {
      $('.pagination').click(function()
        //spelling error | (paginacion => pagination)
        {
            location.href=$(this).attr("href");
        });
      });
```

Or if you just want to append #nav to the location, then use this.

```js
    $(function() {
          $('.pagination').click(function()
            //spelling error | (paginacion => pagination)
            {
                location.href+="#nav";
            });
          });
```

If you could, please elaborate and add to your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, just jumping through the "unanswered question" queue.